# Google did not update my application in Play Store very long time, more than 3 weeks

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

My update to application did not updated in the Play Store. The application package id is: net.interkontakt.ikdating. I published last update 04 January 2018, now is 30 January 2018 but application still not updated in Play Store.

I did not get any errors. The release status:

Jan 4, 11:02 PM: Full rollout.
(Promoted from beta 1.0.12)

Application have status "Published".

The communication with Google support gives nothing. Their answer:

> I took a look at some things on my side and it seems your app is still being reviewed.  Unfortunately, because my team is not part of
>   the review process, I'm not able to say when you can expect the
>   process to finish, nor can I provide any other information.  I
>   apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> I suggest that you do not submit any new versions of the app until the
>   previous submissions have been reviewed.  Please note that all
>   submissions, including Alphas, are reviewed before they are
>   published.

Is anyone have similar problems that update to the application is not published for a weeks? How it can be solved?

UPDATE: Today is 15 Feb 2018. More than a month passed after latest update upload and more than 2.5 months passed after last successful published update (last successfully published update is v1.0.5, version code 10005 uploaded at 04 Dec 2017). Even Alpha version (v1.0.13 version code 10013, uploaded at 29 Jan 2018) still not available to Alpha testers. It stuck with 1.0.5 version, Google support still not give any useful info, only this response below:

> As stated previously, I'm not able to comment on why your app hasn't
>   finished the review process yet.  All I'm able to see is that the
>   process hasn't been finished. Right now, all you can do is wait.  I
>   apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Did your problem get resolved?

Comment: Hello. I see, that your app on Play Market is live. How long it took for update?

Answer (score 1):

Google always tries to publish an app as soon as possible. So if the review is taking a long time, that will be because the review is difficult.

The most likely reason is you are doing something that is risky for app users:

- you have code in your app that might be malware, or looks like it might be malware
- your app is very close to breaking the Play store terms and conditions
- some other difficult legal issue

The team would then need to think very hard about whether what you are doing is allowed, and this process could take a while.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. 
My application is hybrid Cordova based application. It is mobile client for our dating sites. 
Most annoying thing that Google support don't say what is possible can be wrong and what we possible can violate.. Only "your application under review and we can't say when it finished". I can't upload new updates because review process started again.
First releases was published in several hours, the  update that stuck uses same codebase without major changes. Today i waiting already 30 days..

Comment: Are you happy saying here what your package name is of your app?

Comment: My app package name is net.interkontakt.ikdating
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.interkontakt.ikdating

Comment: What about an update having this issue, when the previous ones didn't and with minor changes? :(

Comment: Its been1 and ahlf month my app is still in pending publication

Answer (score 0):

Here are the different statuses that can be displayed for your app:

**Draft:** App hasn’t been published on Google Play.
Note: If the Publish app option isn’t available, click Why can’t I publish? for more information or check your app’s pages on the left menu to make sure you’ve included all required information for your app.

**Pending publication:** App is currently being processed for publishing.

**Published:** App is published and available on Google Play.

**Rejected:** App has been rejected and wasn’t published due to a violation of Google Play policies. More information about the violation is available near the top of your app’s pages on the Developer Console. Once you make a change to your app to address the violation, you can submit it again.

Suspended: App is suspended due to a violation of Google Play Policies (Content Policy, Developer Distribution Agreement).

An email with details about the suspension is sent to the account owner.